# iphone post multipart

Tags: iphone, image, post, alasset

I am trying to upload image and other details using the multipart post method. I went through the following link

http://lists.apple.com/archives/web-dev/2007/Dec/msg00017.html

But I am just not able to tweak it to how I want it as I am not able to under stand the content-disposition and things like that. My code for sending the other details are here below.

```
postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"u=username&p=pass&color=red&date=12];
```

I need to send this as well as an image from the gallery. I am using ALAsset to access the image. PLease help. I am a new bee in iphone

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to upload file with multipart. It's pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks, and can you please tel me or guide me to a link where I can know what is content-disposition and how to use that

Comment: I think that if you use the library all is set correctly. You can take  a look to the sample code. Anyway you can read that discussion on upload and Content-Disposition.

Comment: Cause I am trying to avoid 3 party libraries as I have used many now. So can you tel whrer I can read about this content-disposition and other things

Comment: I think that you complicated your project without a third party lib for that, anyway take a look to what Content-Disposition is: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt

Comment: What I understood from it is that its used for recognizing its corresponding namespace in the server right?